# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' when running a script using the run command

Tags: python, windows, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn webscraping and when running a script using the run command on Windows, it shows an error in cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\MyPythonScripts\k.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bs4, requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

It only happens using the run command, the script fine on the PyCharm IDE though.

Comment: You need to install the module first.

Comment: I have the module already installed, as i said, the script works using the PyCharm IDE.

Comment: Well, pycharm and your terminal are running different versions of python. One has the module installed, while the other does not.